# What is the difference between passing a structure by pointer or by value in this case?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

So I am working through the C Primer Plus book and I came across a programming assignment on structures and files. The main goal is to make a seat reservation program for a plane.

I defined the following structures,

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short identification_number;
    unsigned short status;
    char last_name[MAX_NAM_LEN];
    char first_name[MAX_NAM_LEN];
} Seat;

typedef struct {
    unsigned short empty_seats;
    Seat seats[]; // Flexible Array Member
} Plane;
```

and I have the following function that prints the identification numbers of the empty seats,

```
/*
 * Function:  print_empty_seats_ID
 * -------------------------
 * Prints a list of empty seats identification numbers of the given plane.
 *
 */
void print_empty_seats_ID (Plane* plane, int num_seats) {

    // Clear the screen.
    system("clear");

    printf("Identification number of empty seats:");

    for (int i = 0; i < num_seats; i++) {
        if (plane->seats[i].status == EMPTY)
            printf(" %d", plane->seats[i].identification_number);
    }
    puts("");

    // Redirect the user to the main menu.
    puts("Redirecting in 4 seconds...");
    sleep(4);
}
```

which is called from another function this way, `print_empty_seats_ID (plane, num_seats);` such that `plane` is a pointer to the plane structure defined previously on the heap and `num_seats` is the total number of seats on the plane.

This function works well, but if I change it to use call by value instead of pointers it prints garbage values as illustrated next.

```
/*
 * Function:  print_empty_seats_ID
 * -------------------------
 * Prints a list of empty seats identification numbers of the given plane.
 *
 */
void print_empty_seats_ID (Plane plane, int num_seats) {

    // Clear the screen.
    system("clear");

    printf("Identification number of empty seats:");

    for (int i = 0; i < num_seats; i++) {
        if (plane.seats[i].status == EMPTY)
            printf(" %d", plane.seats[i].identification_number);
    }
    puts("");

    // Redirect the user to the main menu.
    puts("Redirecting in 4 seconds...");
    sleep(4);
}
```

In this case the function is called this way `print_empty_seats_ID (*plane, num_seats);` and outputs the following nonsense `Identification number of empty seats: 64 0 0`.

My question is why does the first function works and the second one doesn't ?

Comment: If anyone feels the urge to down vote this post, please state your reasons clearly.

Comment: I did downvote ,and only then I noticed that it has a flexible array member, so I cancelled my downvote! And I am looking for a duplicate

Comment: I cannot find one.

Comment: Well, I guess that's kind of good! Let's wait for an answer then.

Comment: In the first example, the compiler knows how much stack space is needed for the pointer. In the second case, it does not know what size the `struct` will be.

Comment: I very much feel with you about the downvoting. However, I learned the hard way that downvoting is intentionally anonymous and that many downvoters appreciate that. Please understand that downvoting is a necessary part of the mechanisms which make StackOverflow what it is. Downvoters who are open about it often learn soon that some people cannot take negative criticism. And they can (even without good reason) become a nuisance for the downvoter. Again, I feel with you (and I did not downvote), but you will probably have to learn to live with this. Also, current DVs: 0, congratulations.

Comment: @Amr Mustafa: In short, in value context a struct type with flexible array member behaves as if the array had size zero.

Comment: @Yunnosch Downvoting definitely is what makes StackOverflow what it is. It kind of guarantees a certain level of "formalism" regarding asking questions. But for me, if I know why I am being downvoted, then I would definitely learn more about it and never do the same mistake twice.

Comment: I fully agree. Consider it a design decision to allow anonymity. Some (lets call them "strong", as a neutral description) indicate reasons for downvoting. Others don't and are not blamed for it. Keep in mind that one upvote cancels five downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a so-called flexible array member, about which the spec states:

> In particular, the size of the structure is as if the flexible array
>   member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply.

So, when you pass it by value, the seats themselves are not copied. When you pass it by pointer, the pointer points to the original Plane which does have seats, so it works..

Comment: Aha! That's still a bit weird. But at least now I know where the problem originates from, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Plane` has a *flexible array member* `seats`, i.e. a trailing array with no specified size. These are defined in [C11 6.7.2.1p18](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18):

> **18** As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member. In most situations, the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply.

The example [6.7.2.1p25](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p25) clarifies this:

> 25 The assignment:
>
> ```
> *s1 = *s2;
> ```
>
> [where both are pointers to structures with a flexible array member] only copies the [non-flexible members]; if any of the array elements are within the first `sizeof (struct s)` bytes of the structure, they might be copied or simply overwritten with indeterminate values.

And function arguments in C are passed *as if* by assignment, therefore this applies to `plane` being passed by value.

Comment: Thanks for both the answer and the reference!